# How to generate 3 random values from an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a method which works to generate one random value of an array, but I don't know how to generate the other two because they all end up just being the same number. 
Here is what I have written, but it just crashes...

```
public void getRandomTopics() {
Random random = new Random();

int index = random.nextInt(group_topics.length);

randomOne = group_topics[index];
randomTwo = group_topics[index];
randomThree = group_topics[index];

if(randomOne.equals(randomTwo) || randomOne.equals(randomThree) || randomThree.equals(randomTwo)) {
    isEqual = true;
}
while(isEqual = true){
    randomOne = group_topics[index];
    randomTwo = group_topics[index];
    randomThree = group_topics[index];

}
topicOne = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
topicOne.setText(randomOne);

topicTwo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
topicTwo.setText(randomTwo);

topicThree = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
topicThree.setText(randomThree);
```

}

If anyone knows an easier way to do this help is greatly appreciated:)

Comment: You need to create random numbers 3 times and not 1 time only.

Comment: Well, since all 3 are extracted in parallel using `group_topics[index]`, without changing the value of `index` in between, *why* would you expect different values?

Answer (score 1):

Create 3 different random numbers:

```
int index1 = random.nextInt(group_topics.length);
int index2 = random.nextInt(group_topics.length);
int index3 = random.nextInt(group_topics.length);
```

Now use these 3 random numbers instead of the same `index` that you generate only once.

---

```
randomOne = group_topics[index1];
randomTwo = group_topics[index2];
randomThree = group_topics[index3];
```